# Convert IgniteFuture to Scala Future

Tags: scala, ignite

It is possible to convert an [IgniteFuture](https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.6/docs/async-support) to a [Scala Future](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html)?

I have written the following code:

```
class ScalaIgniteFuture[T](future: IgniteFuture[T]) {
  def toFuture: Future[T] = {
    val result = Promise[T]
    future
      .listen(f => {
        result.tryComplete(Try{
          f.get()
        })
      })

    result.future
  }
}
```

It is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you can use `implicit` class pattern to extend the API.

```
import scala.util.Try

implicit class IgniteFutureUtils[T](igniteFuture: IgniteFuture[T]) {
 def toScalaFuture = {
   val promise = Promise[T]()
   igniteFuture.listen { k =>
     promise.tryComplete(Try(k.get))
   }
   promise.future
 } 
}
```

Comment: forgot `class` keyword